# Finding a powerset of conditional set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The questions asks:

For $A = \{x\ |\ x = 0 \text{ or } x ∈ P(\{0\})\}$ determine $P(A)$.

and I think $P(A) = \{ 0 , \{0\}, \{0,\{0\}\} , \emptyset\}$

Is this correct? or did I misinterpret the question?

Comment: This set is just $\{ 0\} \cup P( \{ 0 \} )$, so it must have only three elements, namely $A= \{ 0, \emptyset , \{ 0\} \}$

Comment: @Crostul You mean $A$ is just $\{0\} \cup P(\{0\})$ right? The power set of $A$, $P(A)$ should be slightly more involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P({0}) = { empty set, {0} }.
A = { empty set, 0, {0} }.
As A has three elements P(A) has eight
which I graciously leave for you to discover.